# DataGridView Row update event

Tags: c#, winforms

I've been searching a while for some kind of a mechanism that would allow to **detect whenever a `DataGridViewRow` of a `DataGridView` changed**, once that `DataGridView` doesn't have a straightforward way to do this. And I've made this implementation

```
public partial class MyDatagrid : DataGridView
{
    public event EventHandler<RowChangingArgs> RowUpdating; 
    public MyDatagrid()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.CellBeginEdit += OnCellBeginEdit;
    }

    private DataGridViewRow oldRow;
    private int currentRow;
    private void OnCellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs args)
    {
        if(oldRow == null || currentRow != args.RowIndex)
        {
            if(currentRow != args.RowIndex && oldRow != null)
            {
                var newRow = this.Rows[args.RowIndex];
                foreach (var cell in oldRow.Cells)
                {
                    foreach (var cell1 in newRow.Cells.Cast<object>().Where(cell1 => !cell.Equals(cell1)))
                    {
                        if(RowUpdating!= null)
                           RowUpdating.Invoke(this, new RowChangingArgs { OldRow = oldRow, NewRow = newRow});
                        oldRow.Dispose();
                        goto called;
                    }
                }
            }
            called:
            oldRow = this.Rows[args.RowIndex].Clone() as DataGridViewRow;
            currentRow = args.RowIndex;
        }
    }

    public class RowChangingArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DataGridViewRow OldRow { get; set; }
        public DataGridViewRow NewRow { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Example:
User edits row 1 and column 1, keeps by editing n columns from same row.
User starts editing other row. Fire event with row 1 old content and row 1 new content.

Is this a good way of doing this, or did I miss something?

Comment: What is the purpose of your inherited `dataGridView`?

Comment: detect whenever a DataGridViewRow of a DataGridView changed. Fire an event when user finish change a row. So while the user is editing the same row it memorizes the current row changes.

Comment: you could use databinding and implement beginedit(), endedit(), canceledit() (described here http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/16408/Discard-changes-in-business-objects) to memorize the current row.

Comment: so in short.. you don't want to duplicate the data in column?

Comment: Instead of doing something when user edits a cell I want to do something when user edits a row. That's what I want. I only verified if the user really edit the cell instead of going to edit and discard the change (I could this when the event fire code).

Comment: @ExpectoPatronum actually something like that come in hand at this moment :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another option... If your data is coming from a "DataTable" or "DataView" (such as a queried result from a backend), a grid's bound data source could be of a DataView.

If this is the case, you could always have it directly from event handlers at the table control management via it's columnChanging or columnChanged events... whichever you are looking for (pre/post changed value).

If so, at the table level, after the data is queried and populated for the grid population, you could then...

```
YourDataTable.ColumnChanging += MyColumnChanging;
```

then have a method...

```
private void MyColumnChanging(object sender, DataColumnChangeEventArgs e)
{
   // just to enforce column name representation, forcing to lower
   string colName = e.Column.ColumnName.ToLower();

   // e.Row has the row that had the change for you to work with, validate, etc...

   switch (colName)
   {
      case "yourcolumnfieldx":
         doSomething;
         break;

      case "anotherfield":
         doSomethingElse;
         break;
   }
}
```

Comment: God you should suggest RowChanged or RowChanging event, is what I'm looking for. Thanks! But I want to do this on grid side...

Comment: @BrunoCosta, yes, I understand that, but the grid is bound to the datatable/table view.  So the data grid actually sends changes to the underlying table/view.  So in essence, you get it trapped up the chain.  Now, for grins... you somewhere else manually try to update the current row of the table/view outside the grid.  It still triggers to the handler I've presented.

Comment: I didn't test my solution yet, but I think I'll stick with it. But yes, your solution would work.

Answer (score 1):

Could you try this:

```
    public string origData { get; set; }


    private void dataGridView1_CellBeginEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellCancelEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
            origData = dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString().Trim(); //Get the original data
    }

    private void dataGridView1_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
    {
        if (dataGridView1.IsCurrentCellDirty)
        {
            if (e.ColumnIndex == 1)
            {
                if (origData != dataGridView1[e.ColumnIndex, e.RowIndex].EditedFormattedValue.ToString().Trim()) //If not equal to original data will trigger
                {
                    //Do stuff
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I wouldn't like to compromise start editing index. I was just trying to know if my code was that bad...

Answer (score 0):

Well you can use This which is more faster than other.
Use **CellEndEdit** Event of The DataGridView

```
        private void datagridView1_CellEndEdit(object sender, DataGridViewCellEventArgs e)
        {
            updateCounter();
        }
```